# Should I cast comparisons to NULL or nullptr?

Tags: c++, type-casting

Let's say I have a **C++** function that looks like this:

```
bool Foo(Bar* b)
{
    if(b == nullptr) {
        return false; 
    }
    // Do stuff
    return true;
}
```

Let's further say that, because of limitations with some of the tools I have that don't support any standards newer than C++03, I have this code in a header:

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
    #define nullptr (0)
    #include <stdint.h>
#else
    #include <cstdint>
#endif // End if C++03
```

My compiler will build this without warning or error. I know I don't *have* to cast `nullptr` but is there a compelling reason that I **should** do it? That is, is there the potential for some bug to creep in relative to to `Foo()` that using `if (b == static_cast<Bar*>(nullptr))` would have avoided *and* that the compiler wouldn't have warned me about (in either C++03 or C++11 or later)?

My reasons for avoiding the cast would be:

1. Adding the cast to every use of `nullptr` seems like it would make the code more cluttered/harder to read.
2. I haven't seen much (if any) code that does so.

Number 2 isn't a good reason in and of itself, so I'm wondering if it's done because it's more convenient for the code author and/or if it's because there really is no compelling reason to do so.

Edit based on proposed answer:
Questions are:

1. If I'm stuck with C++03 now but still want to plan for C++11 in the future, is the best option to stick with legacy `NULL` being set to an integer value and all the best-practices that come with it?
2. If I'm stuck with something of the `#define NULL (0)` variety, should I always apply a cast? For example: `if(b == static_cast<Bar*>(NULL))` is not something I see done very much and I'm wondering if this is out of laziness or if there are good reasons to do or not do this in the case of comparisons (like null pointer checks exemplified above).

Comment: You wouldn't need to add the cast to every use of nullptr, you could create a template function, say "CheckIfNull<T>" and do the cast in there. To make the code a little more readable. =) My instinct is to believe the cast would be a good idea, but I'm honestly not sure. I'm interested to find out the answer to this question as well!

Comment: @CodingHero: "*Number 2 isn't a good reason in and of itself*" Yes, it is. What isn't a good idea is using `nullptr` when you really mean `NULL`. If you have code that needs to compile on pre-C++11 compilers, then you should universally use `NULL`. Pretending that `nullptr` and `NULL` are the same thing (as you're doing here) is a bad idea.

Comment: I like to treat `NULL` and `nullptr` as interchangeable with `0`, even though there could be some obscure case where that fails. If it does, I'll just avoid that platform or library or whatever. :-D So I'd just do `return b != 0;` I get that it's less expressive and more ambiguous than  `NULL`, but dunno, I like plain old zero. Plus I worked in codebases where people treated NULL as zero for integer and boolean-related logic which was retarded, like `int x = NULL;` which ruins the whole meaning of NULL anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas My reason for saying "Number 2 isn't a good reason in and of itself" was in the vein of doing something "because everyone else is doing it" isn't a good reason, which motivated me to ask for more concrete reasons here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Let's further say that, because of limitations with some of the tools I have that don't support any standards newer than C++03, I have this code in a header:

This is a fantastically bad idea.

The expression `(0)` is (more or less) equivalent to the C++ definition of the `NULL`. The thing is, `nullptr` was invented specifically to deal with shortcomings of the `NULL`.

Therefore, pretending that they are in some way equivalent will only confuse readers. It will make people used to C++11 write code that has different behavior when compiled on C++03 compilers. For example:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(Bar*);

foo(nullptr);
```

C++11 tells us that this *must* call `foo(Bar*)`. But your C++03 macro will instead call `foo(int)`. Since `foo(NULL)` would cause the same problem, `nullptr` was invented to stop that.

So having C++03 code that *looks like* C++11 code but *behaves* differently is a terrible idea.

`nullptr`, by design, pretty much never needs to be cast to a specific pointer type. The only exception is if you're calling some kind of function of the form:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T* p);
```

But even then, you can just use `foo<ActualType>(nullptr)` and get the same effect as `foo(static_cast<ActualType*>(nullptr))`.

Your not-`nullptr` needs casting in the same circumstances that `NULL` does. Indeed, since it is essentially equivalent to `NULL`, you should just use `NULL`. And therefore, you have all of the caveats that `NULL` has.

And FYI: it's pretty much impossible to create a type in C++03 that has identical behavior to C++11's `nullptr_t` type. You can get close, by using implicit conversions and so forth. But there will always be corner cases where it doesn't work.

So stop promising `nullptr` behavior that you cannot ensure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited original post to make questions obvious. Your post says that the answer to #1 is clearly "yes, use `NULL" but I'm not clear on the answer to #2 or the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @CodingHero: regarding #2: Casting is only needed if there could be confusion if the null-pointer-constant (NULL, 0, etc.) should be interpreted as an integer or a pointer. When it is identified as being used in a pointer context, the compiler is required to do the right thing.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks! That's the input I was looking for.